# looping backwards through a vector

Tags: r

I want to calculate the number of NAs there are directly before a value in a vector. I am currently trying to use a nested "while" loop since that worked to calculate the number of NAs after. Here is my code with a sample vector, I keep getting 1 for the NA values:

```
x <- c(1:10)
x[3:6] <- NA
    for (i in 1:length(x)){
        if (is.na(x[i])){
            j <- i
                while (is.na(x[j])){
                j <- j - 1
                }
            x[i] <- j - i
         }
         else{
         x[i] <- x[i]
    }
}
```

This returns

```
[1,2,-1,-1,-1,-1,7,8,9,10]
```

The value that I want back would be

```
[1,2,0,1,2,3,7,8,9,10]
```

edit - I added the last brace and fixed the output values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
f1 <- function(x){
   x1 <- is.na(x)
   rl <- rle(x1)
   x[x1] <- with(rl, sequence(lengths[values]))-1
 x}

f1(x)
# [1]  1  2  0  1  2  3  7  8  9 10

f1(xN)
# [1]  1  0  1  2  3  6  7  8  0  1  2  3  4  5  6 16 17 18 19 20
```

#### Update

If you want a result similar to @Jonas post for the second case "xN"

```
indx <- is.na(xN)
xN[indx] <- seq_along(xN[indx])-1
xN
# [1]  1  0  1  2  3  6  7  8  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 16 17 18 19 20
```

#### data

```
x <-  c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)
xN <- c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 7L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L)
```

Comment: Thank you, the first answer is what I am looking for. These values will be used to impute the missing values.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
replace(x, is.na(x), (cumsum(is.na(x)) - 1)[is.na(x)])
```